# /posts/{id} route is blocking /posts/create in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my ChallengesController I have these routes:

```
public function show($id) {
 $challenge = Challenge::find($id);

 if (!$challenge) {
   return back()->with('error', 'Challenge does not exist');
 }

 $projects = $challenge->projects;

 return view('challenges.show')->with(['challenge' => $challenge, 'projects' => $projects]);
}

 public function create() {
  if (auth()->user()->role === 'user') {
     return back()->with('error', 'You are unauthorized to do that');
  }

  return view('challenges.create');
 }
```

In my web.php routes I have these routes:

```
Route::get('/challenges/{id}', 'ChallengesController@show');
Route::get('/challenges/create', 'ChallengesController@create');
```

Whenever I want to go to `/challenges/create` it thinks I have to go to `/challenges/{id}` and is thinking the `{id}` is "create". But in my other controller where I just specified

```
 Route::resource('projects', 'ProjectsController');
```

it has the same route structure when I do `php artisan route:list`, but it's working and my custom `/challenge` routes are not.

Is there a way to override the `/challenges/create` or am I doing something wrong. I am using Laravel version 5.7.20.

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the two routes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

or even more simpler, change the order of declaration:

```
Route::get('/challenges/create', 'ChallengesController@create');
Route::get('/challenges/{id}', 'ChallengesController@show');
```

Comment: This is the actual answer. Constraining the placeholder may work if you are dealing with numeric ids, but it won't work if the placeholder is meant for slugs for example.

Comment: @Namoshek That's wrong. You can use the regular expression as constraints. It is all about adding the regex pattern matching your id parameter. For example, '^[0-9]+(?:-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$' this pattern will allow the slugs like 1234-unique-name

Comment: @invalid-bot Didn't say constraining the input doesn't work. But it may not work in certain situations, e.g. when you allow slugs with the pattern `^[0-9a-z\-]+$` which also matches the route `create`.

Comment: It is a good catch. But we can surely overcome this problem by designing a proper regex pattern for our slug. Also, the Laravel documentation suggests defining the additional routes before the Route::resource() https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 2):

From Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints)

> You may constrain the format of your route parameters using the where
>   method on a route instance. The where method accepts the name of the
>   parameter and a regular expression defining how the parameter should
>   be constrained:

```
Route::get('challenges/{id}', function ($id) {
    //
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Now only numeric values will be accepted as the parameter `id`.